# Create Context Menu on single click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, contextmenu

I am trying to create a context menu. When the user clicks inside canvas(HTML5), a context menu should appear and When an item in the menu is clicked, some functions should be called.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please go through this jsfiddle link this might help you to achieve this.
In this example the orange area is canvas and if you will right click on it, it will show the context menu.

```
function createCustomMenu()
{
     $(".box").unbind("click").bind("click", function (event) {
        // Avoid the real one
      event.preventDefault();

        $("#custom-menu").hide(100);
        // Show contextmenu
        if ($("#custom-menu").show() === true) {
            $("#custom-menu").hide(100)
            // In the right position (the mouse)
            css({
                top: event.pageY + "px",
                left: event.pageX + "px"
            });
        } else {
            $("#custom-menu").show(100).
            // In the right position (the mouse)
            css({
                top: event.pageY + "px",
                left: event.pageX + "px"
            });
        }            
    }); 
}
```

now if user will uncheck the checkbox then it context menu will be disable.if user will check then only it will show he context menu.so i have updated this link also please see the working example..

click on this link to see the jsfiddle example:-http://jsfiddle.net/TnbYm/22/

use this

Comment: thanks.  In your example, a menu is displayed when the user clicks the right mouse button. Actually I want  a menu when the user clicks inside the canvas.

Comment: Use Devendra Soni's answer and bind to the `click` event of the canvas instead of the `contextmenu` event.

Comment: yup do that sorry for replying late...thanks markE :)

Comment: dev : why are you adding a check box?  When I bring down the mouse or move away from menu, menu is not hiding. Context menu is displayed outside the canvas region also.

Comment: if you want to hide the context menu on clicking on outside then use this code and (ignore checkbox functionality)
$(document).on('click' ,function(e) {      
      $("#custom-menu").hide(100);
});

Comment: can you edit the code in jsfiddle and remove the checkbox in html? if I ignore checkbox, where should I call createContextMenu function. can you use <canvas height=300 height=300> <!-- displaying menu when user clicks inside the canvas --> </canvas>  instead of using div with id -canvas.